# Error Message error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I believe my problem may have to do with the way I initialized my string. But I am unsure as to why it is giving a problem when I try to assign it a value then proceed to increment the pointer.

```
int read_file( char *file_name )
    {

        char ch;
        char *string = '\0';
        FILE *file;
        int i = 0;

        file = fopen(file_name, "r");//opens the file

        if(!file){
                return 0;//file not opened
        }else{
                while((ch = fgetc(file))!= EOF){
                        if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'z'){
                                string++ = ch;
                                continue;
                        }
                        string = '\0';
                }
                return 1;
        }
        return 0; //file not opened
    }
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings! Your compiler has smoething to tell.

Comment: And `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char` intentionally.

Comment: `string++ = ch;` is this actually allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line triggering the compiler error is:

```
string++ = ch;
```

Since `string` is a pointer, `string++` is also a pointer.  Further, because the pointer on the LHS of the assignment is the result of the increment, it is a non-modifiable 'lvalue'.  You need:

```
*string++ = ch;
```

Now you're assigning to the thing the pointer points at (and then incrementing the pointer).

You also have a problem at:

```
string = '\0';
```

This is a funny way of writing `string = NULL;` or `string = 0;` (setting the pointer to null) when what you want is `*string = '\0';` (null terminating the string).

You still have a problem: `string` points to an empty and non-modifiable string literal.  You haven't allocated any space for it to point to.  You might use something like this:

```
char buffer[256];
char *string = buffer;
```

You then need to worry about not overflowing the end of the buffer that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate some memory for the string:

```
#define MAX_CH 128

char string[MAX_CH];
```

then you can use it with an index ranged from 0 to 127:

```
string[i] = ch;
```

your inner loop should be something like:

```
int i = 0;
while( i < MAX_CH && (ch = fgetc(file))!= EOF){
    if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'z'){
         string[i] = ch;
         i++;
         continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the source of the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
One, string++ is like writing string = string + 1, you can't do it on a assignment.
You'll get an error saying that left value must be modifiable, (string++) is not a modifiable value.

Two, before writing into memory you must allocate it first, so you have two options, either you allocate enough memory to contain your string on the stack:

```
char string_buffer[1024];

char *string = &(string_buffer[0]);
```

or, you can use a malloc/realloc scheme, but that's a slightly more complicated code, something along the lines of:

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE 64
#define GROWTH_FACTOR 2
char *string_ptr = (char *)malloc(INITIAL_SIZE); // Allocates INITIAL_SIZE bytes.

if (!string_ptr) { /* malloc can return null value, when no memory is available. Handle here. */}

char *string = string_ptr;

// Doing stuff here, string outgrows it's boundaries.

string_ptr = (char *)realloc(string_ptr, INITIAL_SIZE * GROWTH_FACTOR);

if (!string_ptr) { /* malloc can return null values, when no memory is available. Handle here. */ }
```

Malloc'd memory must be freed eventually or you'll experience memory leaks.

Stack allocated strings (char[]) should not be returned to the calling function - since when it no longer 'lives' when the function on whose stack it was allocated returns.

Either way, you must use allocated memory to build your string.